# UWP - Loading images in a folder

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am making an images browser application for Windows 10 UWP.
And I am trying to use any of these two approaches:

1. Select single image, then load and display it, but also show all
   images in this folder to make user possible to browse all images in
   this folder.
2. Select folder, then show all images in this folder
   to make user possible to browse all images in this folder.

So, the main idea is not to load each image separately with FilePicker, but allow user to browse all images in a selected folder, like it is done in a standard Photos app in Windows 10.
But currently I cannot make working any of these two approaches. For example, in this code:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
var filesList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count; i ++)
{
   string filePath = filesList[i].Path;
   BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath));
}
```

my **bitmap** object is never initialized. I suppose it depends on some kind of sandbox limitations, but I cannot understand what should be done to be able to access all images in a selected folder.

Comment: There are several possible reasons for the issue. One is that the `Path` property is only set if the file has a path in the user's file-system. Only because you find it via picker doesn't mean it has a system path. I reckon though that your `Uri` constructor throws an exception when it gets an empty path. Anyway, how do you know the `bitmap` variable is never initialized? Have you debugged? If so, at what point do you know it is not initialized? Add an `int j = 0` into the line after `BitmapImage bitmap = ...` and put your breakpoint there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting Source using stream instead Path

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count; i++)
            {
                using (var stream = await filesList[i].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                }

            }
```